# using a generator's current state to create a delayed iterator

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to understand how to iterate through a generator based on a condition, and to return only the current state without calling next() when that condition is not met.

For instance, given a repeating series of integers from 1 to n, how can I create an index starting at 0 that is frozen until a condition is met by the next value in the series?

My attempt is:

```
def generator():
    number = 0
    while True:
        number +=1
        yield number
gen = generator()
start = gen.next()
def f(x):
    if x>5:
        current = gen.next()
        return current
pd.Series(list(itertools.chain(np.arange(10),np.arange(10)))).apply(f)
```

which returns

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     2.0
7     3.0
8     4.0
9     5.0
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    NaN
13    NaN
14    NaN
15    NaN
16    6.0
17    7.0
18    8.0
19    9.0
```

but the output should be

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     1.0
7     2.0
8     3.0
9     4.0
10    5.0
11    5.0
12    5.0
13    5.0
14    5.0
15    5.0
16    6.0
17    7.0
18    8.0
19    9.0
```

however, an else condition in frozenIndex like current = start will always return the saved first generator value.

Comment: Your functionality isn't clear to me, but why not use a class that implements the iterator protocol? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter

Comment: Given a list [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] I would like to return [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4] (i.e. do not call .next() on the generator until a value > 5 is reached in the sequence.) I am not sure how to implement a wrapper on the generator that only starts it once, instead of every time the wrapper is called.

Comment: But if you're not calling next how do you know when you get to 5?

Comment: Well you start at 0, and if the function frozenIndex(x) sees an x>5, it gives the signal to the generator to call next. So my function frozenIndex is a wrapper for gen.

Comment: So you're delaying the source iterator until the value it would have been had you not been delaying it is some trigger value, then you replay it?

Comment: This feels like a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, exactly

Comment: @DSM Good call. I'm sure there's a better solution, eg filtering the data, rather than using an oddball generator to produce the desired indices. OTOH, I _like_ writing oddball generators. :)

Comment: I've thought on this more and I still don't see how that example is supposed to work at all - `itertools.chain(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))` creates a single iterable, there's no way to tell which of the two sources we're currently in, so I don't see why the freeze is expected to apply to both of them, and the output includes values from none of the sources. Also I'm guessing the initial value is the first value of the source iterator, but that's not explicit. I'm sure you could do something with a class-based approach, but the spec is currently unclear.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I am not looking for an amendment to my own solution. I was merely pasting my own attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing by sending data into the generator via its [`.send`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) method. Here's a (relatively) simple example.

```
def conditional_counter():
    ''' An infinite counter that freezes on the last value 
        if the sent-in value is False-ish
    '''
    yield
    value = 0
    while True:
        condition = yield value
        if condition:
            value += 1

counter = conditional_counter()
counter.send(None)

for s in 'abcdefghijklmnop':
    val = counter.send(s == 'c' or s >= 'h')
    print(s, val)
```

**output**

```
a 0
b 0
c 1
d 1
e 1
f 1
g 1
h 2
i 3
j 4
k 5
l 6
m 7
n 8
o 9
p 10
```

---

The first call to `.send()` *must* pass `None` as the arg, otherwise you get

```
TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

So we take care of that with

```
counter.send(None)
```

and the first `yield` statement in the generator. FWIW, a "naked" `yield` yields `None`, just like a naked `return` returns `None`.

---

Here's a more complicated generator which can be passed any iterable.

```
def conditional_counter(iterable):
    ''' An iterator that freezes on the last value 
        if the sent-in value is False-ish,
        or if the iterable runs out of items.
    '''
    it = iter(iterable)
    yield
    value = next(it)
    while True:
        condition = yield value
        if condition:
            try:
                value = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                pass


counter = conditional_counter(range(9))
counter.send(None)

for s in 'abcdefghijklmnop':
    val = counter.send(s == 'c' or s >= 'h')
    print(s, val)
```

**output**

```
a 0
b 0
c 1
d 1
e 1
f 1
g 1
h 2
i 3
j 4
k 5
l 6
m 7
n 8
o 8
p 8
```

Comment: How does the .send() method know that the data it is being sent is the condition to check?

Comment: @michel The `.send` method _doesn't_ know what the data it sends is used for, it just sends it to the generator, and that data becomes the result of the `yield` expression, so in my scripts above it gets assigned to `condition`. Once the sent data arrives at the generator you can do what you like with it. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29193387/4014959) another small example. I wrote that one a couple of years ago, so it's for Python 2, but it's easy enough to convert to Python 3.

Comment: One more question, why is the first yield (None) statement necessary? Can we not go straight to the while True loop?

Comment: @michel As I said in the answer, "The first call to `.send()` **must** pass None as the arg". So it's _impossible_ to send the condition data in the first `.send()` call. That's why I have the `counter.send(None)` in the calling code and the "dummy" `yield` in the generator. I realise that this is a difficult topic, and I'm still only a beginner at using `.send` myself, but I suggest you experiment with it to become more familiar with how it behaves.

Comment: if my understanding is correct, 'yield' is now an expression, so whatever given by (yield value) is assigned to condition, unless condition is not None. So if you send something like 'x>2' to the generator, for iterations where x>2 is True, True is assigned to the yielded value?

Comment: @michel Exactly. The "result" of a `yield` expression is whatever the previous `.send` call sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a `flag_val` with **0.0**

```
flag_val = 0.0

def frozenIndex(x):
    if x>5:
        current = gen.next()
        flag_val = current
    else: 
        current = flag_val
    return current
```

This should solve what you are trying to do but you cannot traverse forward and backward on **yield**.

Comment: This gives the error:
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag_val' referenced before assignment"